# array_merge(): error when including wp-load.php

Tags: php, wordpress, phpbb

I'm runing a brand new install of Wordpress 4.1 and PhpBB 3.1.2. I want to connect Wordpress to PhpBB therefore I added following in the *overall_header.html* file :

```
<!-- PHP -->
require('../wp-load.php'); 
<!-- ENDPHP -->
```

Result is that I get a PHP error :

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mydomain.ru/htdocs/wp-includes/load.php on line 52: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: `overall_header.html` <- is this your file? with the php code in it? Does `*.html` gets handled like `*.php` ?

Comment: overall_header.html is a native template file from phpBB, it's possible to add custom php in it.

Comment: Ah ok, show us please the file `load.php` from line 50-60, because there is your error

Comment: It's quite informative `Argument #2 is not an array`. Check what it is. This #2 arg.

Comment: It's true, but the error is generated from wp_fix_server_vars() function from load.php which are both native function/file from Wordpress and shouldn't be modified.

Comment: It appears that at this moment $_SERVER is empty. Which is weird because I use it somewhere else (REMOTE_ADDR) and it works.